# Send a Input, but retain Url formatting - Php

Tags: php

**Code that Generates the HTML Form:**

```
<form action='inc/q/prof.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
</form>
```

**Php Code that is referenced in `<form action =`   **

```
<?php
// Insert Comments into Database that user provides
$comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addComment']);

// following line has changed:
$pID4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$cID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseInfoDD']);
$username = "####";
$password = "####";
$pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=####', $username, $password);
$pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);'); 
$sth4->execute(array($comm, $pID4, $cID ));

?>
```

Comment: Dong a `mysql_real_escape_string()` AND using parametrized queries is overkill: It will break strings that contain `'` or `"`

Comment: And can you clarify where pID is supposed to come from? Is it in the form, or in the target URL?

Comment: pID is being pulled from a database table called 'Professor'

Comment: Should the $comm var just be `$comm = $_POST['addComment'];` then

Comment: @user yup. Re pId, at the moment you are pulling it from the GET variable. Please show how you are passing it to the script

Comment: The html has this $comm variable 'addComment'  since the comment textbox name and id='addComment' as shown in the html above.

Comment: How do I keep this in the url upon submission on the html form

Comment: @user so pId is not in the request at all? Can  you show the full HTML of the form?

Comment: I added the full form to my post above. Does this help>

Comment: pID is not in the html form itself, that is in the 'php' file listed above

Comment: pID is within the variable $pID4

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**
I assume you call `prof.php?pID=120` and then you display the given form? And when you click the form the action references your PHP code? If so, then change the php file which prints your form to this:

```
<?
$pID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
?>
<form action='inc/q/prof.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
  <input type="hidden" name="pID" value="<? echo $pID; ?>" />
</form>
```

Then, in the script handling your form submission, you can access the `pID` value via

```
$_POST["pID"]
```

as seen in my first edit, below:

---

**Edit:** Your PHP script would then look like this:

```
// Insert Comments into Database that user provides
$comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addComment']);

// following line has changed:
$pID4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$cID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseInfoDD']);
$username = "###";
$password = "####";
$pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=####', $username, $password);
$pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);'); 
$sth4->execute(array($comm, $pID4, $cID ));
```

The hidden input field is the best way to pass the variables, since you can access it like a normal submitted POST variable (compare it with your `$_POST['courseInfoDD']`).

---

But remember to **never** use this for security relevant information, since this data can be viewed and changed (e.g. by javascript injection).

Comment: Can I see this with my code please? Can you also explain why I would want to use a hidden form field ?

Comment: @user700070 Check my edit... I can't show you more on the form-generating site, since you did not post any code (other than those two lines of form)

Comment: Michael, that is the whole form, its composed of only (1) input field to gather the comment

Comment: When I try the above php code, it gives me the error: ` Column 'pID' cannot be null' `

Comment: I have the url too of the initial form being 'prof.php?pID=273'

Comment: @user Please edit your question and include the code how you generate your form.

Comment: The form, is just one field within <form> tags that links to the php code file (which is shown above) called prof.php